# Angular 4: router.navigate() does not ensure to stop execution rest of the codes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular-router

I am looking for a better way of handling **router.navigate(['/some-route'])**.

My code is like below

```
class SomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    router.navigate(['/some-route']);
    ...
    console.log('This line will be logged.');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...
    console.log('This line will also be logged.');
    ...
  }
}
```

In the above code, both the **console.log** will be logged though navigation is called.

> I know that it happens as **router.navigate()** is just a function and not a termination statement and behaves according to JavaScript behavior.

My exception is, none of the logs should be in Browser Console.

---

***Can anyone help me with better solution to handle the above scenario so that I can ensure rest of the code is not being executed after navigation?***

Answer (score 1):

`ngAfterViewInit` will be always executed,You may want to use `CanActivate` guard , so try somthing like this :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class SomeComponentGaurd  implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router :Router) {}

  canActivate() {
     if( /** some condition*/){
          this.router.navigate(['/some-route']);
        // will access to the component
        return false;
     }else{
         // won't access to the component
         return true;
     }
  }
}
```

routing config :

```
export const AppRoutes:RouterConfig = [
  { 
    path: 'some-cmp',
    component: SomeComponent,
    canActivate: [SomeComponentGaurd]
  }
];
```

this will prevent `ngOnInit` from being executed.

A simple work around without using a **AuthGuard**:

```
class SomeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  private getOut : boolean = false;
  ngOnInit() {
    ...
    if(/** some condition*/){
       this.getOut = true;
       return router.navigate(['/some-route']); // don't forget to return
    }

    ...
    console.log('This line will  be logged.');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    ...
    if(this.getOut){
       return;
    }
    console.log('This line will also be logged.');
    ...
  }
}
```

this should work too, but is not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My problem is, in my component, there are some heavy logical implementations called asynchronously in which the Component View is depending on and redirection is also happening based on the logic. If I move them to **AuthGuard** here, I need to run the same implementation in the component again.

Comment: it's a good practice to move those logical implementations to a new service so you can easily use it inside an AuthGuard, see the update for a simple workaround.